# Drawing a window for a hog object detector in matlab using libsvm

Tags: matlab, histogram, libsvm, gradient

I am creating a multiclass classifer using HOG features and libsvm. I have a video feed and I've segmented the feed into frames and analysed each frame indvidually for an object. I can detect the object but I would like to draw a window around the detected object with either a colour code for the window or an annotation for that object, is there a function in libsvm matlab that can help to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Computer Vision Toolbox, check out the [insertShape](http://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/insertshape.html) Method.
It allows you to easily draw shapes onto an image.